# Extract image based on roi

Tags: matlab

I have an image with a lot of noise (256x256 uint8), so I made a roi containing values 0 and 1 with the true image marked as 1 and noise marked as 0.

How do I extract the true image using the roi I made?

It should be something like: If the coordinate x,y is 1 according to the roi, then keep it, if not then dont add it in the new image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be as simple as

```
yourImage(roi)
```

or

```
newImage = NaN(size(yourImage)); %Or perhaps zeros instead of NaN
newImage(roi>0) = yourImage(roi>0)
```

If this does not work, please give your variable sizes.

Here is an example of how it should work:

```
% Suppose this is your image
yourImage = uint8(round(255*rand(256)));
% Suppose this is the mask of zeros and ones you created
roi = uint8(yourImage < 10);

newImage = NaN(size(yourImage));
newImage(roi>0) = yourImage(roi>0);
```

Comment: [link]http://imgur.com/EGP8YaR
This is my variables. It doesn't work with the construction of the matrix, and I get this error when trying to call image(roi):

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

The "image" is 'abdomen', which is a .mat file

Comment: @user2782743 I see roi is of type `uint8`, try whether it helps if you use `roi>0` instead of `roi` (compact way to cast it to `logical`)

Comment: @user2782743 Do you get an error or does it simply not do what you expect? In the first case please mention the error (and what you did to try and solve it) or in the second case please say what it does and what you expected.

Comment: I'm getting the same error:  Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: @user2782743 Please use `dbstop if error` to find the line on which the error occurs and what the variables are at that moment. Also see my updated answer for an example of how it can be done.